# Appending files with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, append

I'm trying to merge files based on a list generated using os.walk() but the last item in the list is almost always omitted from the append.

Here is the code I'm using with ArcGIS Pro.

```
feature_classes = []
for dir, fols, filenames in os.walk(temp):
    for filename in filenames:
        if 'file.shp' in filename:
            feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dir, filename))
blank_clu_temp = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(temp, 'Blank file Template',template=f'{temp}\\Output Shapefile 1\\file.shp', spatial_reference=f'{temp}\\Output Shapefile 1\\file.shp')
for x in feature_classes:
    arcpy.Append_management(x, blank_file_temp,schema_type='NO_TEST')
```

The resulting template that has been appended to frequently has n-1 appends, however it inconsistently appends all files. All the schemas and field maps are identical and are appended without problem. At times doing time.sleep(15) has periodically solved the issue but not consistently. I don't know if there is some sort of hold on the files that I need to dump but the only list element to never get appended is always the last.

Comment: This seems a pure Python issue, which could probably be resolved just by using the first five lines and adding `print` statements between 3 & 4 after 5.

Comment: I'd simply merge list to what you call blank. Less code and works much faster.

Comment: Originally I tried that method but it has the same problem. @FelixIP

Comment: What if you `random.shuffle` the list, is it still the last item that cause problems? Use `os.path.join` instead of `f'{temp}\\Output Shapefile 1\\file.shp'`

Comment: Something to do with your OS? Delayed writing? Perhaps append list by empty fclass.

Comment: I was using 'gdal.VectorTranslate()' to convert from XML to SHP and needed to set the converted variables to None to release them.